# how to make showcase solid background color

Tags: android, android-view, showcaseview

I whant to change to change the background color to be a solid background, and not faded like its implemented.
i cant find in the code where the fading happens.

can anybody help?

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be late but maybe someone else might stumble across it. In the `styles.xml` of the `SampleActivity`, there is a style by the name sv_backgroundColor. Use that, the first two characters after the '#' are the alpha value and the next six are the Hex color code.

`<item name="sv_backgroundColor">#3300A621</item>`

or

`<item name="sv_backgroundColor">#ffxxxxxx</item>`

to have it not trasparent

Comment: This should be added in our own style.xml?

Comment: @OrcusZ yes, add it to your own (in your style that you are using, obviously)